# Optimizing multivariable without known function (only input & output), but it's a polynomial

Tags: optimization, python

I have multiple set of input (5 parameters) and output from an unknown function. But I know this is a polynomial function.
What method can I use to optimize to find the polynomial variable that can fit those parameters? A lot of optimization method that I know need a known function.

I have tried optimizing the  polynomial function below using simulated annealing, but still fails.

```
y_pred = p1*p2*p3*p4*w1*x**5 + p1*p2*p3*p4*w2*x**4 + p1*p2*p3*p4*w3*x**3 + p1*p2*p3*p4*w4*x**2 + p1*p2*p3*p4*w5*x + p1*p2*p3*p4*w6
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like Numpy's `polyfit` be suited to that ? Given 6 sampling points, your polynomial `y_pred` can be fitted uniquely.

Comment: Are you sure that the form of a polynomial you've given is correct? 
For me it sounds like you're dealing with a polynomial of five variables $y=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ in which one has to find parameters for each term.